# How to access variables from different class in tkinter to use in different functions?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with accessing the data which is a different class. I have found some solutions in this platform but still, I could not implement it in my script. I will appreciate your help regarding this.

I tried to design a login page, including user_name and password. After the user fills those fields and click the login button, I want to get those variables (from page 1) to use in different functions(printing in def `printName()`).

```
class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs,bg='white')

        label = tk.Label(self, text="",bg='white')

        heading= tk.Label(self, text="ENTER OM", font=("ALGERIAN",40,"bold"), fg="black",bg='white').pack()
        user_name= tk.Label(self, text="User Name :", font=("arial",20,"bold"), fg="black",bg='white').place(x=15,y=201)
        password= tk.Label(self, text="Password :", font=("arial",20,"bold"), fg="black",bg='white').place(x=15,y=305)

        self.shared_data = {"last_user_name": tk.StringVar(),"password": tk.StringVar()}
        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.shared_data["last_user_name"]).place(x=210, y=214)
        last_user_name = self.shared_data["last_user_name"].get()

        button_1=tk.Button(self,text="Log In", width=12,height=3,fg="white",bg="blue",font=("Arial",10), command=printName).place(x=350,y=450)

        button_3=tk.Button(self,text="Close", width=12,height=3,fg="white", bg="red", font=("Arial",10),command=close_window).place(x=180,y=450)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="", bg="white")
        button_2=tk.Button(self,text="Om Creation", width=10,height=3 ,fg="white",bg="blue",font=("Arial",10), command=OMcreat).place(x=750,y=400)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


class Page3(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)       
        label = tk.Label(self, text="")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)
        p3 = Page3(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        root.configure(bg='white')
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p3.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=p1.lift)
        b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=p2.lift)
        b3 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 3", command=p3.lift)

        b1.pack(side="left")
        b2.pack(side="left")
        b3.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("OM credantials")
    root.wm_geometry("1000x750+0+0")
    root.configure(bg='white')
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

    root.mainloop()


def close_window():
    root.destroy()
    driver.close()


def printName():
    print(last_user_name)
```

Comment: You need to read up on instance variables to get the hang of this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3

Comment: Like you inherit class Page to all other classes, you can use the same method to inherit Page2 to the class where you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printName` and `close_window` methods will be evaluated at last, unstead of declaring them outside a class move them to `Page1` and change buttons commands:

```
class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        button_1 = tk.Button(..., command=self.printName)
        button_3 = tk.Button(..., command=self.close_window)

    def printName(self):
        print(self.last_user_name.get())

    def close_window(self):
        root.destroy()
        driver.close()
```

You have a `NameError: name 'OMcreat' is not defined` in `Page2`.

```
class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        button_2 = tk.Button(..., command=self.OMcreat)
        button_2.place(x=750,y=400)

    def OMcreat(self):
        pass
```

The value of `last_user_name` should be empty until a user fills in it.
replace it with

```
self.last_user_name = self.shared_data["last_user_name"]
```

and use `get` method when needed.

`heading` variable will be of `None` type which is the result of `pack` method (same with `place` method), so change it to the following and do the same with other variables:

```
heading= tk.Label(...)
heading.pack()
```

**EDIT**
The reference of the MainView instance is already available in `args`.To access pages instances, you can define them as an instance variable:

```
self.p1 = Page1(self)
```

Comment: ,Thank youuu very much for this  detailed explanation.  It worked and taught me a lot.

Comment: ok I had a look at but how can I get the value of `self.shared_data` (or `self.last_user_name` for that matter) on page2 and 3? I am getting 'Page2' object has no attribute 'last_user_name', where I change the OMCreat to a print statement with `print(self.last_user_name)`...?

Comment: `last_user_name` should be declared in `Page2` *(self.last_user_name = ...)* to be able to use `self.last_user_name`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use global variables or just save the p1 class:

```
logvar=''
def save_login(l):
    global logvar
    logvar=l
def get_last_login():
    return logvar
```

Or use `self.p1` instead of `p1` in MainView and `main.p1.shared_data['last_user_name']`
The second method is better. Global variables are not recommended in general.